# Как сделать отображение книг pdf или doc в web приложении на java?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, pdf, doc

Приветствую вас!

Я сейчас изучаю JavaEE и вот решил написать свой web проект - онлайн библиотека для просмотра книг онлайн на JSP + Servlets. И все вроде шло относительно хорошо пока не возник вопрос: а как сделать показ этих книг на страничке? Книги есть в .pdf, есть в .doc в БД mySQL. Конвертировать их в какой то один формат не проблема. Но что для одного формата, что для другого у меня нет понимания как сделать их отображение. В веб технологиях я не очень силен. Может какое-то решение на java?

Comment: Java и EE тут ни при чем. Если вам нужно отобразить на веб-странице PDF, найдите соответствующую клиентскую (javascript-овую) библиотеку.

Comment: [например, pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) от Mozilla

Comment: Можно и не pdf. Просто я с js не знаком вообще.